# Is $L_{\omega+1}$ uncountable?

Tags: set-theory

I'm trying to understand the [constructible universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe), but I'm having trouble understanding what $\operatorname{Def}(X)$ means (especially since I don't really understand the $\models$ symbol).

Is $L_{\omega+1}$ an uncountable set? Why or why not? If not, what's the smallest $\alpha$ for which $L_\alpha$ is uncountable?

Also, if anyone can explain the $\models$ notation used in the article (or provide a link to an explanation), that would be very helpful.

Comment: From the linked article: ‘If $\alpha$ is an infinite ordinal then there is a bijection between $L_\alpha$ and $\alpha$, and the bijection is constructible.’ $L_{\omega+1}$ is countable, and the smallest $\alpha$ for which $L_\alpha$ is uncountable is $\alpha=\omega_1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks. I didn't see that. Shouldn't that be posted as an answer? Also, assuming the V=L axiom, what's the smallest $\alpha$ such that $\mathcal P(\omega)\in L_\alpha$? I'm assuming it's $\omega_1$ again, but I don't know.

Comment: I don’t know off the top of my head; I never worked much with the constructible universe.

Comment: No, it is $\omega_1+1$. That $\mathcal P(\omega)^L\subset L_{\omega_1}$ is the condensation lemma. Once you have this, $\mathcal P(\omega)^L$ can be defined, so it belongs to the next stage.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\mathrm{Def}(X)$ consists of all subsets of $X$ first-order definable in the structure $(X,\in)$ from parameters. What matters here is that there are only countably many formulas, and only $|X^{<\omega}|$ possible tuples of parameters from $X$, so there are only $\aleph_0|X^{<\omega}|$ possible elements in $\mathrm{Def}(X)$. If $X$ is countable, this means that $\mathrm{Def}(X)$ is also countable.

If you are not comfortable with the description of $\mathrm{Def}$ in terms of first-order definability, note that this set can also be realized by applying to $X$ a countable number of (finitary) operations, explicitly listed for instance in Chapter V of the first edition of Kunen's set theory book. These operations correspond to Boolean operators (underlying the fact that if $\phi,\psi$ are formulas, so are $\lnot\phi$ and $\phi\land\psi$) and projections (underlying the fact that if $\phi$ is a formula, so is $\exists x\,\phi$). Again, this implies, by the same counting as in the previous paragraph, that $\mathrm{Def}(X)$ is countable if $X$ is.

An easy inductive argument now gives us that if $\alpha$ is a countable ordinal, then $L_\alpha$ is countable as well. On the other hand, another (slightly more involved) inductive argument shows that $L_\alpha\subsetneq L_{\alpha+1}$ for all $\alpha$, which implies that $L_{\omega_1}$ is uncountable.

Comment: So, assuming that $\{\{\}\}\in L_2$, does that mean that $\{\{\{\}\}\}\in L_2$? What would $\Phi$ be, then? $\forall x((x\in y)\iff(x=\{\{\}\}))$?

Comment: Well, not quite. A set $a$ is in $\mathrm{Def}(X)$ iff there is a formula $\varphi(x,y_1,\dots,y_n)$ in the language whose only non-logical symbol is $\in$, and there are elements $b_1,\dots,b_n$ of $X$ (not necessarily different) such that $a=\{c\in X\mid (X,\in)\models \varphi(c,b_1,\dots,b_n)\}$. That is to say, $a$ is the set of elements of $X$ that $X$ thinks have  property $\varphi$ with respect to the parameters $b_1,\dots,b_n$.

Comment: If $1=\{0\}=\{\{0\}\}\in L_2$, to show that $\{1\}\in L_3$ (note the subindex $3$ rather than $2$), you need a formula $\varphi(x,y_1,\dots,y_m)$ and elements $r_1,\dots,r_m$ of $L_2$ such that $\{1\}=\{t\in L_2\mid (L_2,\in)\models\varphi(t,r_1,\dots,r_m)\}$. A silly such formula is $\varphi(x,y)\equiv x=y_1$, and take as parameter the element  $1\in L_2$. Obviously, the only $t$ that $L_2$ thinks equals $1$ is $1$. Naturally, the same argument, but changing the parameter, shows that for any $a\in L_2$, we have that $\{a\}\in L_3$.

Comment: (Slightly more interesting is the fact that we can find such a formula $\varphi(x)$ witnessing that $\{1\}\in L_3$ with no other free variables than $x$.)

Comment: (Sorry about the typo two comments up, I meant for the beginning of the comment to say: If $1=\{0\}=\{\{\}\}\in L_2$,...)

Comment: OK, I think I understand at his better. May I ask for another example, though? Specifically: Which $L_\alpha$ contains the set $\{0,2,4,\dots\}$, the set of even numbers? Is it $L_{\omega+1}$? $L_{\omega+2}$? (Also: I assume that $\omega\in L_{\omega+1}$, because I can use the formula $\Phi(y)=y\text{ is an ordinal}$, which can be written using formal logic symbols.)

Comment: $L_{\omega+1}$ contains as elements $\omega$, the set of even numbers, the set of primes, and many others. And yes, the $\Phi$ you suggest witnesses that $\omega$ is in $L_{\omega+1}$.

Comment: Really? I didn't expect that. What $\Phi$ can we use for the primes??

Comment: The usual definition works, you can define addition and multiplication of ordinals.